# Character table and simple groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I know that if two nonabelian simple groups have the same character table, then they are isomorphic. But this uses the classification of finite simple groups. Is there any proof or idea without using the classification of finite simple groups?

Comment: Math.overflow related queries: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57375/character-tables-and-simple-groups and  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34424/number-of-finite-simple-groups-of-given-order-is-at-most-2-is-a-classification . It would seem, given the comments there, that the answer is "no".

Comment: As a general rule, anything specific that holds for all simple groups, they are $2$-generated, there are at most three (even finitely many) of a given order, there are finitely many sporadics, etc., can only be proved via the Classification.